# PL/SQL - Aggregate values & Write to table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I am just starting to dabble in PL/SQL so this question may be very straightforward. Here is the scenario:

I have several checkboxes which carry a weighted numeric value. For example:

> Checkbox I --> Value '5'
>   Checkbox II --> Value '10' 
>   Checkbox III --> Value '15'
>   etc.

The form would have 15 checkboxes in total and the end-user can select anywhere from 0 to all 15. As they select the checkboxes, the total weight would get calculated and a final numeric value would be displayed. For example. checking off 3 Checkbox I & 2 Checkbox III would = 45 points.

Now the total value of 45 would equal to a separate value. Example:

> At 0 points, value = 'Okay'
>   1-15 points, value = 'Error' 
>   16-30 points, value = 'Warning' 
>   31+ points, value = 'Critical'

The form itself is built within Oracle APEX and I can do it using Dynamic Actions but using PL/SQL may be a better solution.

In summary, I'd like the hidden field to first calculate the total from the checked checkboxes and then use that total to figure out the value of either Okay, Error, Warning, or Critical.

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it is better if we're going to use javascript on your case since we have to manipulate DOM and events of the checkboxes. If you want to display/change item values and get values at runtime, then javascript is better in doing that than PLSQL unless you want to submit your page every time you check/uncheck a box in your page which is not advisable. 
Here is my solution for your question.

First, create a `Display Only` item on your page. This is where the values "Okay", "Error", "Warning", or "Critical" will appear. And its very important to set it's default value to 0. Then inside your page's "Function and Global Declaration" part, put the following functions:

```
        function getcheck(checkbox_id,displayOnly_id){
        var chkboxName = document.getElementById(checkbox_id + "_0").getAttribute("name");
        var chks = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
        var howmanychecks = chks.length;
        var currentSum=0;
        var v_remarks = "";
        for(x=0;x<howmanychecks;x++){
            chks[x].setAttribute("onchange","checkIfchecked(this,\'" + displayOnly_id + "\')");
            if(chks[x].checked){
                currentSum = currentSum + Number(chks[x].value);
            }
        }
        if(currentSum==0){
            v_remarks = "Okay";
        }
        else if(currentSum>0 && currentSum<=15){
            v_remarks = "Error";
        }
        else if(currentSum>15 && currentSum<=30){
            v_remarks = "Warning";
        }
        else{
            v_remarks = "Critical";
        }
        document.getElementById(displayOnly_id).value = currentSum;
        document.getElementById(displayOnly_id + "_DISPLAY").innerHTML = currentSum + ": " + v_remarks; 
    }

function checkIfchecked(p_element, displayOnly_id){
    var v_difference;
    var v_sum = Number($v(displayOnly_id));
    var displayOnly_display = displayOnly_id + "_DISPLAY";
    var v_remarks = "";
    if(p_element.checked){
        v_sum = v_sum + Number(p_element.value);
        $("#" + displayOnly_id).val(v_sum);

    }
    else{
       v_difference=Number($("#" + displayOnly_id).val())-Number(p_element.value);
       if(v_difference<0){
          v_difference=0;
       }
       $("#" + displayOnly_id).val(v_difference);
    } 
    if($("#" + displayOnly_id).val()==0){
        v_remarks = "Okay";
    }
    else if($("#" + displayOnly_id).val()>0 && $("#" + displayOnly_id).val()<=15){
        v_remarks = "Error";
    }
    else if($("#" + displayOnly_id).val()>15 && $("#" + displayOnly_id).val()<=30){
        v_remarks = "Warning";
    }
    else{
        v_remarks = "Critical";
    }
    document.getElementById(displayOnly_display).innerHTML=$("#" + displayOnly_id).val() + ": " + v_remarks;

}
```

The above functions will get the sum of the values of those boxes that are checked. A value of a box will be taken out of the current sum if it is unchecked as well. It will also display the remarks for the current checked points whether if it is "Okay", "Error", "Warning", or "Critical".

In your "Execute when Page Loads" part of your page, add the following line:

```
  getcheck(nameofyourcheckboxitem,nameofyourdisplayonlyitem);
```

where `nameofyourcheckboxitem` is the name of your Check Box and `nameofyourdisplayonlyitem` is the name of the Display Only item you have just created.

Here's a sample line on how to use the function that I've given you:

```
    getcheck("P1_MYCHECKBOX","P1_MYDISPLAYONLY");
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot and let you know the results! :)

Comment: Hi @vance - this works very well! One question though - when I hit save and reload the page it does not maintain the existing value. For example, if I have it at critical and close the form and come back, it is back to 0 and selecting a checkbox adds +5 rather than 'existing value + 5'.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is more than perfect. :)

Comment: Just wondering, why wouldn't you leverage jQuery in your code? That would make it a whole lot more readable (and cross-browser safe, but op did not mention browsers to support so w/e I guess). At the very least, the apex javascript api's would help a lot too in order to facilitate codemaintenance.

Comment: Im just starting to see the wonders of jquery, that's why my code is a mixture of javascript and jquery. I always incorporate jQuery in my codes whenever I know how